Firebase RTDB: Pagination long time execution issue
My Android app holds local cache of trips timeline data from RTDB. Full timeline operating day contains 10K nodes (5-7MB). When I get all day data in single request, sometimes the app crashes with OutOfMemory error. So I need use pagination, but I've got an issue with it.
Request of reading full data (10K nodes) takes approx 10-12 seconds in my case. When I make several requests, reading by 2K nodes each time for instance, each request takes also approx 10 seconds. As a result total time of getting data enlarged from 10 (single read) to 50 (paged read) seconds. Can I fix it? Thanks.

private fun fetchDayStationsPaged(dayTag: String, lastNodeId: String? = null, stations: MutableList<StationCloud> = mutableListOf(), callback: (data: List<StationCloud>, errorMessage: LoadError?) -> Unit){
    val path = String.format(TimelineManager.KEY_TIMELINE_STATIONS, dayTag)

    val query = if (lastNodeId == null)
        database
            .getReference(path)
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToFirst(2000)
    else
        database
            .getReference(path)
            .orderByKey()
            .startAfter(lastNodeId)
            .limitToFirst(2000)

    Timber.d("loader recursion stations $dayTag/${stations.size}")

    fetchDayStations(query) { data, errorMessage ->
        if (errorMessage == LoadError.NotExist)
            callback(stations, null)
        else if (errorMessage != null)
            callback(emptyList(), errorMessage)
        else {
            stations.addAll(data)
            fetchDayStationsPaged(dayTag, data.last().nodeId, stations, callback)
        }
    }
}

private var loaderDisposable: Disposable? = null

private fun fetchDayStations(ref: Query, callback: (data: List<StationCloud>, errorMessage: LoadError?) -> Unit){

    loaderDisposable?.dispose()
    loaderDisposable = FirebaseHelper
        .dbReadAsSingle(ref)
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnDispose {
            callback(emptyList(), LoadError.Cancelled)
        }
        .subscribe ({ snapshot ->
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val stations = mutableListOf<StationCloud>()
                snapshot.children.forEach { item ->
                    item.getValue(StationCloud::class.java)?.also { station ->
                        stations.add(station.copy(nodeId = item.key))
                    }
                }
                Timber.d("loader fetchDayStations stations size = ${stations.size}")
                callback(stations.toList(), null)
            } else
                callback(emptyList(), LoadError.NotExist)
        }, {
            Timber.e(it)
            callback(emptyList(), LoadError.CantGet)
        })
}

private fun dbReadAsSingle(ref: Query): Single<DataSnapshot> {
    return Single.create { emitter ->
        ref.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            Timber.d("runQueryCloudFirst task succeed = ${task.isSuccessful}")
            if (task.isSuccessful && emitter.isDisposed.not()){
                Timber.d("runQueryCloudFirst children size = ${task.result.childrenCount}")
                emitter.onSuccess(task.result)
            } else
                task.exception?.also {
                    //todo check a bug: timeout exception doesn't work when offline
                    //https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5771
                    Timber.e(it, "runQueryCloudFirst")
                    emitter.onError(it)
                }
        }
    }
}


If I understand correctly, you are loading the data from Firebase's local cache. In that case the behavior makes sense, as Firebase actually has to read the full stations data from the local cache to then return a slice of that data. So it'll have to load the full data for each sliced, leading to the linear performance problem you have.
There is nothing within the Firebase Realtime Database API you can change about this. The best option typically is to change your data model to fit the use-case.
A good practice when dealing with NoSQL databases is to model your data for what you display on the screen, and to only load data that you actually display to the users.

In a mobile scenario it seems quite unlikely that you're displaying 5-7MB of data on a single screen. Even 10% of that would already be significantly more than average. So more likely, you're loading a lot of data that you're not actually, directly displaying. That's where your solution lies:

If you're only displaying a subset of each child node, consider creating a different top-level node that only contains the information you need for each child node. For example: station_list_info could contain just the few properties you actually display. That node will likely be much smaller, so lead to fewer memory problems.
If you're displaying aggregate values based on the child nodes, consider actually storing those aggregate values in the database - rather than calculating them on the (each) client. If you store the aggregate value like this, you'll update it whenever you create/update/delete a station - so writing the data becomes more involved. On the other hand, reading the aggregate value then becomes a trivial operation.

Both of these are common approaches when using a NoSQL database, where you typically end up with a data model that reflects your use-cases. To learn more about this, I recommend reading NoSQL data modeling techniques
